# Alterar objeto de uma listview

Tags: android, listview

Tenho uma `listview` populada por um Objeto, porém eu queria saber se tem como ao alterar o objeto, eu consegui-se alterar a *view* correspondente a esse Objeto, e não a `listView` inteira.

Comment: Usar o `notifyDataSetChanged` no seu `Adapter` não vai alterar todos os objetos, apenas os visíveis. Uma alternativa é setar uma tag `View.setTag(...);` para identificar cada `View` retornada pelo `Adapter` no método `getView(...)` e no `ListView` percorrer os filhos (`ViewGroup.childAt(index)`) verificar pela tag e modificar a `View` manualmente.

Answer (score 1):

Crie um método para alterar o item da lista, adicione as condições para capturar o item especifico que você deseja alterar. Você precisa ir item por item na lista, use o `for` para tal:

```
for (Object ob : listObj) { 
    if('vouAlterar'.equals(ob.getNome())) {
        ob.setNome = 'Alterei';
    }
}
```